# Recognize dates in string at Flutter

Tags: flutter, named-entity-recognition

I need to achieve 'recognize dates in string at Flutter(Dart)'.
First of all I searched for 'recognize dates in string' then I found [this](http://natty.joestelmach.com/doc.jsp) url.
This url is working like what I want.
But I need this at Flutter(Dart).

Is there anyone know how can i achieve this feature?

BTW, I couldn't find any pub.

Edit: Example string 'is that okay tomorrow 2 pm'. I need to recognize dates like '03.01.2021 14:00:00'.

Edit 2: Imagine a form which is have some fields like title, start date and others. When user set title with 'meet with friends tomorrow morning', I want to set start date field with tomorrow's full date (if today is 02.01.2021, then field should be 03.01.2021).

Also added.

[image]

Thank you all,

Utku Y.

Edit 3: For now we will use [this short way](https://dateparser.io/).

Comment: It would be nice if you would clarify some specification.  Do you want it to match exactly what that referenced package matches, or just the two examples you gave, or something in between?  What are your precise requirements?

Comment: Thank you Randal for your response. I edited again, added image and another example.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can translate either the English description or the actual ANTLR code to https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser.  You can probably also do it with a regular expression that is built-up from smaller regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you fr your response. I'll examine this pod and regex examples.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` has  a `parse` method

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse('1974-03-20 00:00:00.000');
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: That doesn't parse nearly as much as the referenced library can.

Comment: Thank you for your response but actually my needs is different a bit. I edited original post.